# How do I get sudo to read my ~/.gemrc file?

Tags: sudo, home, gem, rails

I'm using Debian Linux, Ruby on Rails 5 on Apache with Passenger.  I crated the file ~/.gemrc

```
gem: --no-rdoc --no-ri
```

However, I'm running the command

```
sudo bundle install
```

and it doesn't seem to be picking up the above.  How do I get "sudo" to recognize my "~/.gemrc" file?

ps - I have to run with sudo b/c the Apache directory from where I'm running this command complains about bad permissions if I don't do this.

Comment: It's better to set the right permissions to your apache directory rather than blindly using `sudo`. But if you want to go this way you have to copy the  `.gemrc` file in the home directory of root which is `/root`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nowadays `sudo` switches your user to root, and in Debian it defaults to rewriting your `$HOME`, so it becames `/root`:

```
$ sudo sh -c 'echo $HOME'
/root
```

So, `$HOME/.gemrc` under root is expected to be in `/root/.gemrc`, and chances are that you want it to pick up a file from your regular user's directory.

The blunt force solution is to do something like

```
sudo ln -s /home/your_user_name/.gemrc /root/.gemrc
```

A little more intricate solution is either to disable `always_set_home` in `/etc/sudoers`.

Another option is to use somewhat complicated way to call sudo like

```
sudo sh -c 'export HOME=/home/your_user_name; bundle install'
```